# probability biostatistics

Tags: probability, statistics

If adult male cholesterol is normally distributed with a mean of 200 and standard deviation = 25

what is the probability of selecting a male whose cholesterol is :

less than 165

greater than 165

then find the 40th percentile value for cholesterol?

Comment: do you know how to use the z-distribution table?

Comment: yes I do but I don't know what is the difference between less and greater… and I have no idea how to find the 40th percentile ?? can you explain please

Comment: are you familiar with cdf of Normal distribution? The answer to the first two question come out from it easily. To answer the third question you need $x$ such that $\Phi(x)=.4$

Comment: @Alex can you please show me how to get the answer, and please explain how to get the 40th percentile

Comment: my answer for less than 165 is .0808 and greater is 1-.0808 which is 0.9192 .isnt that right

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666728/biostatistics-probabilities-given-mean-and-standard-deviation

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answers to the first two questions are $\Phi \bigg( \frac{165-200}{25} \bigg)$ and $1-\Phi \bigg( \frac{165-200}{25} \bigg)$, where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of Normal distribution, which I leave you to find. The solution to the third problem is to find $x$ such that $\Phi(x)=0.4$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: ok now I have the values of less than 165 and greater than 165, but to be honest I have no idea how to find the 40th percentile. can you explain it in details. thanks in advance

Comment: a 40th percentile is a value on x-axis that corresponds to $40 \%$ of standard Normal CDF: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-find-a-percentile-for-a-normal-distribution.html